# Navigate directly to a URL in angular 4

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to navigate to a demo page using `www.domain.com/demolink` but instead I am thrown to a errorhandler. But if I create a `<a routerLink="/demolink">QT Demo Link</a>` routerLink on the `www.domain.com` I am able to navigate to the `Demo` page.

My app routes look like this

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'demolink', component:QtDemoLoginComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'app/:errorCode', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'errorHandler', component: ErrorViewComponent},
  {path: '**', component: ErrorViewComponent}
];
```

What is wrong? Please advice.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It goes to my custom ErrorHandler. `/demolink` in network tab the status code shows 302 found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set up your server to fallback to index.html when the resource isn't found so that the Angular router can handle the request. [The  Angular docs mention this in the section on deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

In my Apache virtualhost file I use [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource)

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

and it works. You can also use rewrite rules but this is pretty short and easy to understand.

Comment: The problem is not the error page. The problem is navigating to the demolink. The ErrorHandler is setup fine.

Comment: If you are typing domain.com/demolink in the url bar and you're not serving anything at that location then you will get an error. if you want it to work you will have to rewrite that url to index.html so Angular can route it. This is a server config issue, You might want to update your question to include your server configuration information like a VirtualHost file or .htaccess file

Comment: So you are saying I have to make an entry in the apache? I am not familiar with the apache server and configs.

Comment: Yes, that's right but it's not too difficult. I updated my answer with a link to the Angular documentation about it

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for Devin. Thank You.